# Getting the count of unique values from mongodb using Spring data

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I am using Spring data with MongoDB. In my database I have information about `tenants`, `stores` and `departments`, `storevisitor` number.
Now I want to get the count of the top five `departments` with `storevisitor` numbers.

Have tried with aggregate functions but couldn't get the desired result.

My code is :

```
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation
            .project("tenantId", "storeId", "departmentId","storeName");

    AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("departmentId", "departmentName")
            .count().as("count")
            .first("tenantId").as("tenantId")
            .first("departmentName").as("departmentName")
            .first("sectionName").as("sectionName")
            .first("roiName").as("roiName")
            .first("objectEntryDate").as("objectEntryDate");

    AggregationOperation sortData = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "totalNoOfShoppers");
    AggregationOperation limit = Aggregation.limit(5);

    aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, group, match, sortData,limit);

    AggregationResults<BatchReportResponse> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,Info.class,Response.class);
```

. The desired output should give me a top five **departments** based on number of **storevisitor** number

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link to update your question and show us the `aggregate()` function code you attempted, as well as some sample documents with the expected output?

Comment: Show us a little bit more about structure of domains and how you tried to aggregate initially.

Comment: Does your code run ? Your projection fields doesn't match the group fields

Comment: yes Sagar, code is running .. but it is  not giving me a desired output.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question but you have left out crucial information; a couple of documents from the collection to show the document structure.

Comment: Try grouping by only `departmentId` and change the `count` alias to `totalNoOfShoppers`.